# How to improve R code to extract identifiers from a structured text file

Tags: r, text, stringr

My goal is to parse a structured text file and extract 4 unique identifiers into an R data frame.

As a first step, I've run

```
c <- read_lines("minex_cochrane.txt")
```

Then, given the character vector c, where each element is a line.

```
c <- c("Record #1 of 3", "ID: CN-00966682", "TI: A multi-center, randomized controlled trial of a group psychological intervention for psychosis with comorbid cannabis dependence over the early course of illness", 
    "SO: Schizophrenia research", "YR: 2013", "VL: 143", "NO: 1", 
    "CC: Drugs and Alcohol", "PG: 138‐142", "PM: PUBMED 23187069", 
    "PT: Journal Article; Multicenter Study; Randomized Controlled Trial", 
    "DOI: 10.1016/j.schres.2012.10.018", "US: https://www.cochranelibrary.com/central/doi/10.1002/central/CN-00966682/full", 
    "", "", "Record #2 of 3", "ID: CN-00917992", "TI: Effectiveness of a self-guided web-based cannabis treatment program: randomized controlled trial", 
    "SO: Journal of medical internet research", "YR: 2013", "VL: 15", 
    "NO: 2", "PG: e26", "PM: PUBMED 23470329", "XR: EMBASE 23470329", 
    "PT: Journal Article; Randomized Controlled Trial; Research Support, Non‐U.S. Gov't; Research Support, U.S. Gov't, Non‐P.H.S.", 
    "KY: Adult; Australia; Female; Health Behavior; Humans; Internet; Male; Marijuana Abuse [psychology, *therapy]; Outcome Assessment (Health Care); Self Care; Telemedicine [*methods]; Therapy, Computer‐Assisted; Treatment Outcome; Young Adult", 
    "DOI: 10.2196/jmir.2256", "US: https://www.cochranelibrary.com/central/doi/10.1002/central/CN-00917992/full", 
    "", "", "")
```

The following detects, then cleans up, my desired unique ID's.

```
library(stringr)
id_l <- str_detect(c, "ID: ")
id_vec <- c[id_l == TRUE]
id <- str_replace(id_vec, "ID: ", "")

pmid_l <- str_detect(c,"PM: PUBMED")
pmid_vec <- c[pmid_l == TRUE]
pmid <- str_replace(pmid_vec, "PM: PUBMED ", "")
cs <- cbind(id, pmid)
```

Producing the following output as desired.

```
> cs
     id            pmid      
[1,] "CN-00966682" "23187069"
[2,] "CN-00917992" "23470329"
```

However, this seems overly cumbersome.  I would like improve my code to do this in a more compact and efficient fashion to facilitate parsing a large file.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

The code assumes, that for each ID: xyz, there is a PM: xyz: following before the next ID: xyz.

```
ids= c[which(grepl("^ID: |^PM: ", c))] # find and select each element starting either with "ID: " or "PM: "
df = matrix(data = ids, nrow = length(ids)/2, ncol = 2, byrow = T) # transforme the vector in a matrix, assuming that the order is allways ID: PM: (so for each ID-entry there has to be a PM entry too) 
df = apply(df,2,function(f) gsub("ID: |PM: |PUBMED ", "", f)) # remove all ID: , PM: , PUBMED from all of the strings
df
```

Answer (score 1):

More concise would be to apply `str_extract()` directly:

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
cs <- data.frame(
  id = str_extract(c, '(?<=^ID: ).*') %>% .[!is.na(.)],
  pmid = str_extract(c, '(?<=PUBMED ).*') %>% .[!is.na(.)]
)
```

**Resulting in:**

```
           id     pmid
1 CN-00966682 23187069
2 CN-00917992 23470329
```

*Caveat:*

This assumes almost perfect consistency/regularity in your data.

**EDIT**

Can be simplified using `na.omit()` that I had forgotten about (credit to Roland):

```
cs <- data.frame(
  id = na.omit(str_extract(c, '(?<=^ID: ).*')),
  pmid = na.omit(str_extract(c, '(?<=PUBMED ).*'))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex with an *or* in a look behind condition:

```
matrix(na.omit(str_extract(c, "(?<=ID: |PM: PUBMED )(.+)")),
       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#     [,1]          [,2]      
#[1,] "CN-00966682" "23187069"
#[2,] "CN-00917992" "23470329
```

Comment: Oh, thanks I felt something like na.omit() existed but couldn't recall.